# i18n testing using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

Have any one used selenium for testing i18n !

Does Selenium provide any kind of I18N/L10N support?  Is it possible
to  verify text based on message keys from a resource file?  What
about checking numbers and dates that might have a different format
because of L10N?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also interested in the correct approach for this issue. Where I work, we usually use the ids to verify certain page or field. But, sometimes you might need to verify some text, which could be using i18n.

Try the following:
If you have a selenium-testing module, have the module where the bundle is placed as a dependency. And then define a ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource in the xml. And than setup the test following this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6251478/521754

Hope that helps!
Cheers!