# Is localization and internationalization testing important while testing an app or website?

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, testing

Is localization and internationalization testing important for applications, mobile applications, or websites?

Comment: may be. that's about as specific as i can be given the details in the question

Comment: Yes.  What's the alternative?  Putting it out there on a wing and a prayer, hoping not to alienate your international audience?  Voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

`Globalisation testing` is important in insuring software can function in any culture/locale.

> The goal of globalization testing is to detect potential problems in
>   application design that could inhibit globalization. It makes sure
>   that the code can handle all international support without breaking
>   functionality that would cause either data loss or display problems.
>   Globalization testing checks proper functionality of the product with
>   any of the culture/locale settings using every type of international
>   input possible.

`Localisation testing` is important for checking the quality of a piece of software in regard to a particular target audience/culture.

> Localization translates the product UI and occasionally changes some
>   initial settings to make it suitable for another region. Localization
>   testing checks the quality of a product's localization for a
>   particular target culture/locale. This test is based on the results of
>   globalization testing, which verifies the functional support for that
>   particular culture/locale. Localization testing can be executed only
>   on the localized version of a product. Localizability testing does not
>   test for localization quality.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to test i18n in app and website because the page you are testing could get translations in your database (missing table, missing field, unknown primary key, etc) or Properties file (missing code, missing language, default language).

a solution is to do selenium test especially if your I18n could be identified in the URL such as:
"http://mywebapp.com/en/category1/index"
"http://mywebapp.com/es/category1/index"

Depending on the architecture of your application, you can test it like this too
[i18n testing using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869113/i18n-testing-using-selenium)