# jsr 303 how to force it to use my resourcebundle?

Tags: java, validation

I have validator class which uses

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
</bean>
```

Besides validator which does more complex validation I also use JSR303 like

```
@NotNull(message="null value is not allowed")
 protected String postCode;
```

I want for JSR to use same file source messages.

```
  @NotNull(message=<SOMEHOW GO TO MY messages_en_US.properties AND EXTRACT SOMETHING LIKE : user.poscode.null>)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246381/getting-localized-message-from-resourcebundle-via-annotations-in-spring-framewor) - it appears to have a solution.

Comment: that doesn't help, I am really bad at evaluating answers based on similar, but not same topics :-(

Answer (score 3):

By default JSR303 validator looks for a file called `ValidationMessages.properties`, which is bundled with the implementation you use.
If you want to add your own constraint validation messages you have to provide your own `ValidationMessages.properties`, and add to it the message.

You can look at [Message interpolation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#section-message-interpolation), Hibernate validator docs.

But what I've just describe its Java EE standard behaviour I don't know if Spring behaves in the same way

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the situation with help of another more focused question of mine on simillar topic. Anyone interested : [javax.validation how to target different locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989649/javax-validation-how-to-target-different-locale)

**Please be aware however that there will be a need in two sets of files including resourcebundle and properties.**