# spring3.0 annotations

Tags: java, spring

I have a property file converterValues.properties having these data valueOne=1,valueTwo=2
  i am trying to use the annotation

```
@Value("#{converterValues.valueOne}")
private transient String dataValue;
```

I want to load all the properties at once not each at a time using converterValues.valueOne

let me know how to get valueOne=1,valueTwo=2 at once using annotation.

I want to avoid defining @value for each key.

Comment: You want all properties to get into a Map of Property and Value . Is this what you need?

Comment: The problem is now for 'n' number of keys present in property file i would have to write @Value defination ,this approach is not good if we have more keys in property file,i just want to avoid writing this.

Comment: yes i want in this way  all properties to get into a Map of Property and Value ,and how to access it in java?

Comment: Maybe similar question to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246381/getting-localized-message-from-resourcebundle-via-annotations-in-spring-framewor

Comment: not similar,here i want to avoid @value defn for 'n' number of keys present in property file

Answer (score 0):

First create a [qualifier annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers), let's call it `@ConverterValues`.

Then declare a bean of type `PropertiesFactoryBean` with the given qualifier.

```
<bean id="converterValues" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:path/to/properties" />
    <qualifier value="your.package.ConverterValues" />
</bean>
```

Now you can inject the properties into your bean:

```
@Autowired
@ConverterValues
private Properties converterValues;
```

**Update**

You could, of course, skip the overhead of defining a qualifier if you are willing to express the dependency explicitly:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("converterValues") // the name of the bean to inject
private Properties converterValues;
```